# why window.onload not fire in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onload

I have some code to open a popup, then resize the it via certain element on the popup page. The following code work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.

```js
var newWin ;
    function openWindow(id) {
        newWin = window.open(url,config,setting);
        newWin.onload= function () {                     
              newWin.resizeTo(newWin.document.getElementById("certainID").offsetWidth,100);
        };
```

In IE10 a popup will come but the *window.load* event will never fire.
I also try *newWin.$(document).ready*  , but seems it is invalid.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `window.onload = function() { //code }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolve this via *setTimeout* to check whenever the element in popup is well-generated, then resize the popup window

```js
var newWin ;
    function openWindow(id) {
        newWin = window.open(url,config,setting);
        var resizePopup = function () {
                newWin.resizeTo(newWin.document.getElementById("certainID").offsetWidth,100);
                newWin.focus();
            };
        var tryResize = function(){
                if(newWin.document.getElementById("certainID")==null){
                    setTimeout(function(){tryResize();},500);
                }
                else{
                    resizePopup();
                }
            }
        tryResize();
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old problem in IE.
One of the best solution is to add `new`.

Normally we write

```
window.onload=function() { alert('hello');};
```

Replace it with

```
window.onload=new function() { alert('hello');};
```

Comment: Yes, using this way the _alert_ will positively popup. However, in this way, both *IE* and chrome will  return *null* for _newWin.document.getElementById("certainID")_ . I find out that _new function()_   will result in firing the window.onload much *earlier* than expected so that the element in popup isn't well-generated.  Finally I resolve this via the workaround written in the _Answer_

Answer (score 1):

If using setTimeout, may be popup perform resizing when window not finish loading yet. I think best solution is using setInterval and check whenever document.readyState==='complete" => call clearInterval() and run resize